# Accepting Paypal Payment directly with iOS without server

Tags: ios, paypal, integration

Is it possible to accept paypal payment directly inside an iOS App (i don't mean via the Paypal iOS app, but my own app) without having our own server to validate the return token? I think it is possible with a javascript button inside a webview, but can it be a native iOS function?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it... but it would involve enormous risk. The reason is that you would have to store your credentials inside the app and then make the call directly. Anyone could then extract the credentials and start using them for their benefit (i.e. [MassPay](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/mass-payments) themselves from your account).

The only way to ensure they don't get your credentials is to keep them server-side, where the client has no access to them.